# Connect to Wi-Fi via command line that requires username and password

Tags: macos, wifi, airport

I am trying to find the command to connect to a wireless access point that is WPA2, and requires both a username and password.

The command `networksetup -setairportnetwork <iface> <ssid> <pwd>` only works if I don't need a user name.

Comment: are you trying to connect a enterprise wpa2?  Sounds like you need a system profile.

Comment: Yes. How does one do that? I'm unfamiliar with system profiles. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It does sound like you are trying to connect to an enterprise network and you have 802.11x authentication.

If this is NOT the case and you need to enter a username/password in a web page, then you may need to create an AppleScript/Automator function to handle that.

In any event, to connect to an 802.11x network with authentication, you need a network profile.  To create one, you either need OS X Server or you can use [Apple Configurator](http://www.enterpriseios.com/wiki/Apple_Configurator).  It's a free application available from Apple.

While it is geared toward iOS, you can create wi-fi profiles then export them.  Once you have the xml file, you import it with networksetup.

Or...

You can edit the xml file directly which is not something trivial.

Comment: I've downloaded Apple Configurator and I see no way of exporting a wi-fi profile.  I also don't know which xml file you are referring to when you say that I can edit them directly. I've googled and searched for them, but have had no luck.